# MSVC 2022 Template Build Errors No Compile-Time Strack Trace?

Tags: c++

I may well just be missing some silly option in the boatload of options available in MSVC 2022 that changed in terms of their defaults (please tell me if so), but I can't seem to get a compile-time stack trace when we encounter errors in the middle of function or class templates.

Basic example in MSVC 2022:

```
template <class T>
void foo()
{
    static_assert(false);
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
}
```

In MSVC 2022 with default settings, all I get is a "static assert failed" kind of message. It doesn't tell me who called `foo`. Whereas in MSVC 2019, I got a full compile-time stack trace letting me know that calling `foo` failed down to the precise line that called `foo`.

I'm really missing that extra info from 2019. But I have a sneaking suspicion that there's some option in Tools->Options I'm not aware about to enable this output behavior again.

Picture:
[image]

Anyone else encountering this issue after upgrading to 2022 from 2019 and/or have a fix for it?

MSVC 2019 as a comparison where I got error messages in templates that are actually usable to help me figure out where/how they occurred!
[image]

Also, I only used `static_assert` to produce a bare minimum and reproducible result. I'm lacking this stack trace on every kind of error that occurs inside a function or class template.

In response to the automated Q for the site:

> I tried going through all the options I could find and searching Google along with this site for answers. In fairness, I'm an old and dumb guy now so I might have overlooked something obvious. I really think that has to be the most obvious answer since MSVC 2022 has been out for a long time now and I figure other people would have complained left and right in ways I could easily find if this wasn't a behavior we can revert. I'm really hoping I'm overlooking something because that would totally suck if we can no longer see the compile-time call stack for errors in class and function templates (that's actually omitting crucial info in many cases, since it may not be an error with the template/callee but an error in the way the caller calls the callee).

**Stack Trace?**

My bad if I used the wrong terminology for this. I got a comment pointing this out. I am thinking about something that is like tracing the call stack (not calling, but evaluating calls in a nested fashion at compile time as we parse, generate AST, generate IR, optimize IR, etc.). That could be a second question as a bonus if I'm using "compile-time stack trace" incorrectly! What's the proper term? English is not my first language as a half-excuse but I'm probably just really dumb!

**Update in Response to HolyBlackCat**
[image]

I just made a project with the default settings using your code and got the type of errors I expect and wanted from MSVC 2019! A sample of the errors I get which match yours:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\memory(3256,5): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\memory(3256,5): message : 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\vector(852,1): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const _Ty&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>,
1>            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>,
1>            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\vector(863,36): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const _Ty&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>,
1>            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>,
1>            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>        ]
```

So that's great and wonderful! I at least like this part of MSVC 2022. But I could swear that I was getting errors in function and class templates in our project that didn't show this for whatever reason. I tried to use `static_assert(false)` as an MVE. But it seems like some cases show us hierarchy of callers and not just the error in the callee and some cases don't... although I still think seeing that even for `static_assert` fails is so useful!

Comment: There's no stack trace during a build for that ... It runs into a static assert for false. It doesn't need to do any more processing. A couple versions ago, MS updated their defaults to be standard compliant on how it processes templates and static asserts. Maybe that's what you're seeing.

Comment: @ChrisMM I might be using the wrong terminology. I mean a compile-time trace of the compiler evaluating the IR and reporting messages as it traces into calls of function templates. I call it compile-time "stack trace" since I assume the data structure from a compiler design standpoint resembles a stack of sorts. But basically the type of "compile-time stack-like trace output that MSVC 2019-" did is what I'm seeking.

Comment: @ChrisMM Although if you have a more specific term for this, I'm all ears! A lot of people I've met into compiler design still call this a stack trace since we're using a stack to evaluate the IR when we need to do so for function calls.

Comment: You may have missed my edit to my comment, since I realized it was just terminology. The issue most likely is in how MSVC was changed on handling templates, in order to follow standard compliance.

Comment: @ChrisMM Ouch! If that's standard behavior, I think it's very painful! Because sometimes an error in calling a function template is in the caller, not the callee, e.g. If we only see error messages pointing to lines of code in the callee, we miss what the caller did incorrectly.

Comment: That's not what ChrisMM is saying. `static_assert(false);` now triggers even if the template is never called, it happens when the template is first seen, so there's no callee at this point. In general, the standard has no say in the error message contents.

Comment: No option for a stack trace, it isn't very useful for a closed-source compiler.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see! I am only thinking in terms of usability. 90% of the time any static assertion failure I encounter, as with a runtime assertion failure, isn't a bug in the code but a bug in the input parameters (ex: passing a negative number to a function that requires N>=0). So it leaves me in the dark wondering who called the function (or function template in this case) with invalid parameters if I can't see who did it.

Comment: No, again, here the `static_assert` fails even if you **never use** the template, because its condition doesn't depend on the template parameters. If it did depend on template parameters, the compiler probably would've given you the stack you're looking for.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think I understand! But I'm also finding this behavior in general with class templates and function templates that don't use `static_assert`. An error that occurs in a function template as a result of its parameters doesn't show me the LOC of the callers who passed invalid arguments for the template parameters. For example, trying to instantiate `std::vector<T,Alloc>` where `T` is noncopyable in a case involving `push_back` instead of `emplace_back`. I get build errors in `std::vector` but not in the caller who used it incorrectly.

Comment: I can't reproduce [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ohxG4v4PT). Yes, the first message points to `<vector>`, but if you scroll down, there are ones referring to the calling code. If you get a different error for this code, can you upload it to pastebin and give us the link?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, that's exactly what I want! I might have made a mistake with that example (just made it up on the fly). I just started off noticing after I upgraded that some errors in function and class templates weren't giving me the "stack trace". I will try it now -- I tried to do a minimal reproducible example involving `static_assert` just to show what I mean but it might be something that's a bit more nuanced as to when it does and doesn't show more detailed and useful error messages.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just gave your example a shot on my end and updated my answer! In short, I get the types of errors I expected and wanted from MSVC 2019 in this case... but I don't in others for some reason.

Comment: This happened to me in rare cases. If you manage to extract a minimal example that reproduces it, you can report it as a bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I will give it a try -- thanks very much! It looks like we hit those rare cases you mentioned immediately upon upgrading, since our projects build fine on two diff versions of GCC as well as MSVC 2019. So I think a lot of the errors we're encountering are ones specific to MSVC 2022, and it's at least a relief to me to know that there's not some change in design to omit this extra info! I will tinker and see if I can come up with MVEs -- we also have a few internal compiler errors which are very uninformative (although I at least knew those were compiler bugs).

Answer (score 1):

Had a chance to test my theory from my comments. The issue is with trying to be standards compliant.

You likely have `/permissive-` flag set, to be standards compliant (default when C++20 is used). This enables two phase name lookups for templates. Under the non-standard parsing which Microsoft did before:

> It parses only the template declaration, the class head, and the base class list. The template body is captured as a token stream. No function bodies, initializers, default arguments, or noexcept arguments are parsed. The class template is pseudo-instantiated on a tentative type to validate that the declarations in the class template are correct.
>
> ...
>
> When it parses a function template, the compiler parses only the function signature. The function body is never parsed. Instead, it's captured as a token stream.

In this, non-standard mode, it ignores the `static_assert( false )`, until it is instantiated from `main`, in which case you get the information about who's instantiating it.

In the standards compliant mode, it does parse the body, and sees the `static_assert( false )` and fails immediately, before any instantiation is done.

If you want the old behaviour, you can turn off the standards conformance by specifying `/permissive` (though I would not recommend this). You can disabled just the two-phase name lookup (again, not really recommended) by specifying `/Zc:twoPhase-`

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase?view=msvc-170

Also, example (side by side) with two phase on and off here: https://godbolt.org/z/MPEWGsYTx (godbolt gives less details in its output than MS, but does show its instantiation)

Note: The compile still gives information on who's instantiating if the issue is with the caller, not the callee.

Funny aside: when MS first did this, they broke their own code in the process, and caused a whole lot of programs to stop compiling because they were using `static_assert( false )` in their Unit test framework ... I guess they forgot to use their own unit testing before pushing it out :P